# Closed form expression‎ of double-way matching problem (Special case of derangement)

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory, derangements

## Is there a "closed form expression‎" for below problem ?

### Problem :

"N" guests gave their raincoats and their umbrellas to the doorman at the entrance of the
“Marlinspike” mansion in order to attend the party. At the end of the night, the doorman was
completely plastered. So, he gave the leaving guests a random raincoat and a random umbrella, in
a way that each person got a pair of raincoat and umbrella in a uniformly random manner.

### Questions :

a. What is the probability that nobody gets back his own raincoat and his umbrella?

b. What is the probability that everybody gets at least his own raincoat or his own umbrella?

#### recall orginal derangement (1 variable):

$$ |\bar{A_1},\bar{A_2},...,\bar{A_n}|=|S|-\sum_{i=1}^n |A_i|+\sum_{i=1 j=1}^n |A_iA_j|-...=n!-\begin{pmatrix}n\\1\end{pmatrix}(n-1)!+...+(-1)\begin{pmatrix}n\\n\end{pmatrix}(n-n)! $$
$$ D_n=n!(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-...+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!})=n!(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!})$$
$$ P(D_n)=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

## Answer :

#### a) derangement with 2 independant variable:

$$ |(\overline{U_1\cup R_1}),(\overline{U_2\cup R_2}),...,(\overline{U_n\cup R_n})|=|(\overline{U_1}\cap \overline{R_1}),(\overline{U_2}\cap \overline{R_2}),...,(\overline{U_n}\cap \overline{R_n})|=$$
$$|(\overline{U_1},\overline{U_2},...,\overline{U_n})\cap(\overline{R_1},\overline{R_2},...,\overline{R_n})|=$$
$$(D_n)^2=(n!)^2\left[1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-...+\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\right]^2$$
$$P(D_n^2)=\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\right)^2$$

#### b) derangement with 2 dependant variable:

$$|(U_1\cup R_1),(U_2\cup R_2),...,(U_n\cup R_n)|=$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}n\\i\end{pmatrix}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-i}\begin{pmatrix}{n-i}\\k\end{pmatrix}.D_{(n-i-k)}.\begin{pmatrix}{n-i}\\{n-i-k}\end{pmatrix}.D_{(k)}\right]$$
so
$$P((U_1\cup R_1),(U_2\cup R_2),...,(U_n\cup R_n))=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}n\\i\end{pmatrix}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-i}\begin{pmatrix}{n-i}\\k\end{pmatrix}.D_{(n-i-k)}.\begin{pmatrix}{n-i}\\{n-i-k}\end{pmatrix}.D_{(k)}\right]}{n!n!}$$
$$=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-i} \left(\frac{(n-i)!}{k!(n-i-k)!} \right) \left( (n-i-k)! \sum_{f=0}^{n-i-k}\frac{(-1)^f}{f!} \right) \left(\frac{(n-i)!}{k!(n-i-k)!} \right) \left( (k)! \sum_{l=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^l}{l!} \right) \right]}{n!n!}$$
$$=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n-i} \left(\frac{((n-i)!)^2}{k!(n-i-k)!} \right) \left( \sum_{f=0}^{n-i-k}\frac{(-1)^f}{f!} \right) \left( \sum_{l=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^l}{l!} \right) \right]}{n!n!}$$

### to more clarification :

[detailed answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU309.jpg)

[you can also test this formula by this desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qjazdsaxlu)

[picture of n=3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFH4W.png)

Comment: I don't agree with either solution.  In the first case, you are interpreting the question as "What in the probability that no one receives his own raincoat nor his own umbrella," but I read it as meaning, "What is the probability that no one receives both his own raincoat and his own umbrella," so I would say it's an ordinary derangement of $n$ raincoat-umbrella sets.  As to the second case, I don't understand what it has to do with derangements.  Everybody receives at least on of his articles.  Where is the derangement?

Comment: @saulspatz

yes in part (a) i agree with you , but in the second part we can't use Complementary method (for each guests if he receives his own raincoat affect on umbrella & vice versa so we can assume this problem like "2 Interwoven derangements"  or a "bipartite matching problem".
to make more vivid sense please attent [this pic.](https://i.ibb.co/C1Q841R/UR3.png)
(when n=3 we accept 11 event from all 36 so p=11/36)

Comment: I see that exactly $k$ guests get their own umbrellas in $\binom nk D_{n-k}$ ways, and so the other $n-k$ guests must get their own raincoats, but why can't the remaining $k$ raincoats be distributed in $k!$ ways?  It seems to me that the number of ways is $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkD_{n-k}k!$$

Comment: @saulspatz

You are missing some events to enumerate !
we know the state space is n!n! (raincoat ! × umbrella ! ) but 
`everybody gets at least his own raincoat or his own umbrella` this sentence means we must enumerate 3 type of events :
1-**guest who correctly own theirs umbrella**
2-**guest who correctly own theirs raincoat**
3-**guest who correctly own theirs raincoat & umbrella**
if you checkout with n=3 (i also attach some link for you) you find your mistake.

Comment: Yes, the people who don't get their own raincoat must get their own umbrella.  I haven't missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have time to write a detailed answer yesterday.

Let us say that exactly $k$ people get their own raincoats, where $0\leq k\leq n$.  There are $\binom nk$ ways to choose which  $k$ people get their own raincoats, and since the other $n-k$ people do not get their own raincoats, there are $D_{n-k}$ ways to distribute the remaining raincoats.

To fulfill the condition, each of the $n-k$ people who did not receive his own raincoat must get his own umbrella, leaving $k$ umbrellas to distribute.  But these are precisely the umbrellas of the people who got their own raincoat.  It doesn't matter how we distribute these umbrellas, since everyone has already received his own raincoat or his own umbrella.  We may distribute the umbrellas in $k!$ ways.

This gives
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkD_{n-k}k!=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!D_{n-k}}{(n-k)!}=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{D_k}{k!}
$$

We may test this when $n=3$.

$$
\begin{align}
n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{D_k}{k!}
&=3!\sum_{k=0}^3\frac{D_k}{k!}\\
&=6\left(\frac{D_0}{0!}+\frac{D_1}{1!}+\frac{D_2}{2!}+\frac{D_3}{3!}\right)\\
&=6\left(\frac11+\frac01+\frac12+\frac26\right)\\
&=6\left(\frac{6+0+3+2}{6}\right)\\
&=11
\end{align}
$$
in agreement with the picture you posted.

To get the probability we must divide by $(n!)^2$ giving the simple expression $$\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{D_k}{k!}$$ or if we use the common notation $!k$ in place of $D_k$,
$$\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{!k}{k!}$$